# Internal server error when using base64 encoded icon on the home page

Tags: web-hosting, php, html, css

I have an "index.html" (or .php - it makes no difference) file in the root / of my hosting space. That "index.html" file has this line of code in it:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

When I try to access my domain name, I get a customized internal server error message "Internal server error, please contact ..". If I remove that line of code, it works.

If however, I create a folder called "test", put the "index.html" file inside it and access the file as "mydomain.com/test" everything works fine.

Any ideas? (i will try a js replacement however, this goes to the general point, of why does the error pop up?)

Comment: Oh. Good one!! It would be interesting to hear what people have to say on this.

Comment: Some kind of mod_security rule?! Does it "work" if you use the same data URI in an `img` element in the `body` of the page? How "customized" is this error? "please contact .." - have you tried? Or is that just a generic message?

Comment: I tried changing the filename from index.html to index.php. But I have the same error.

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: It works fine for me in the webroot folder for a domain on Apache and I've tried it with 3 different hosting environments/providers, I imagine you'll need to contact your hosting provider if this bothers you. It also works using the `<img src="" />` method.

Comment: What this is working if I using  <img src="" /> method.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue that is specific to your hosting provider.  The likely explanation is that they have a check in place to look for malware on the home page of your site.  Base64 encoded JavaScript is often used to obfuscate JavaScript inserted by a hack.  Their malware scanner triggers when it detects any Base64 encoded data.

To resolve the issue you would need to contact your web host.  They may be able to disable this check for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following source code in a file name *index.html* in the root folder of a published website with a domain ending .com:

```
<html><head>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</head><body>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</body></html>
```

Here's a screenshot of the result in Firefox (v38.0.1), showing your icon working from base64 encoded inline data both as a favicon in the browser tab and also as a static image within the body section of the web page.

[image: Screenshot of icon working from base64 encoded inline data]

As mentioned before in a comment I've tried this file with 3 different hosting environments/providers with consistent results and have been unable to reproduce the issue you had described where an *Internal Server Error* is generated by Apache.

Tested/known working configurations:

- 2.6.18-164.el5, Apache v2.2.3, PHP v5.3.4-dev
- 3.2.61-grsec-modsign, Apache v2.2.29, PHP v5.4.37
- 2.6.18-471.3.1.el5.lve0.8.72, Apache v2.4.12, PHP v5.4.40